# Cross platform global hotkey application that I could package with my application?

Tags: cross-platform, global, hotkeys, global-hotkey

So, I have cross platform application that I made, I need to fire it off on a global key command, which the sdk I am using is not able to do. I was wondering if there is any existing app that I could package with my app to act as the global hotkey manager for my application (license that would allow that). The problem is the cross-platform side of it. I have found many apps, but I have found ones for Windows, OS X or Linux/Gnome individually. Is there anything that is all of these in one?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found such hotkey management app yet.

But since you develop your own app, this cross-platform library might suffice:
https://pkg.go.dev/golang.design/x/hotkey#section-readme

Quoting bits of the page:

> ### hotkey PkgGoDev  hotkey
>
> ---
>
> cross platform hotkey package in Go
>
> ```
> import "golang.design/x/hotkey"
> ```
>
> #### Features
>
> ---
>
> - Cross platform supports: macOS, Linux (X11), and Windows
> - Global hotkey registration without focus on a window

...

> ### Who is using this package?
>
> ---
>
> The main purpose of building this package is to support the [midgard](https://changkun.de/s/midgard) project.
>
> To know more projects, check our [wiki](https://github.com/golang-design/hotkey/wiki) page.
>
> ### License
>
> ---
>
> MIT | © 2021 The golang.design Initiative Authors, written by [Changkun Ou](https://changkun.de/).

What do you think of the following specifics?

> ### Overview
>
> ---
>
> Package hotkey provides the basic facility to register a system-level global hotkey shortcut so that an application can be notified if a user triggers the desired hotkey. A hotkey must be a combination of modifiers and a single key.
>
> Note platform specific details:
>
> - On macOS, due to the OS restriction (other platforms does not have this restriction), hotkey events must be handled on the "main thread". Therefore, in order to use this package properly, one must start an OS main event loop on the main thread, For self-contained applications, using [mainthread](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.design/x/hotkey/mainthread) package. is possible. It is uncessary or applications based on other GUI frameworks, such as fyne, ebiten, or Gio. See the "[examples](https://github.com/golang-design/hotkey/tree/main/examples)" for more examples.
> - On Linux (X11), when AutoRepeat is enabled in the X server, the Keyup is triggered automatically and continuously as Keydown continues.
> - On Linux (X11), some keys may be mapped to multiple Mod keys. To correctly register the key combination, one must use the correct underlying keycode combination. For example, a regular Ctrl+Alt+S might be registered as: Ctrl+Mod2+Mod4+S.
> - If this package did not include a desired key, one can always provide the keycode to the API. For example, if a key code is 0x15, then the corresponding key is `hotkey.Key(0x15)`.
>
> THe following is a minimum example:
>
> ```
> package main
>
> import (
>   "log"
>
>   "golang.design/x/hotkey"
>   "golang.design/x/hotkey/mainthread"
> )
>
> func main() { mainthread.Init(fn) } // Not necessary when use in Fyne, Ebiten or Gio.
> func fn() {
>   hk := hotkey.New([]hotkey.Modifier{hotkey.ModCtrl, hotkey.ModShift}, hotkey.KeyS)
>   err := hk.Register()
>   if err != nil {
>       log.Fatalf("hotkey: failed to register hotkey: %v", err)
>   }
>
>   log.Printf("hotkey: %v is registered\n", hk)
>   <-hk.Keydown()
>   log.Printf("hotkey: %v is down\n", hk)
>   <-hk.Keyup()
>   log.Printf("hotkey: %v is up\n", hk)
>   hk.Unregister()
>   log.Printf("hotkey: %v is unregistered\n", hk)
> }
> ```

I am not author/a related person, just a googling bypasser.  Cheers!